# Replacing multiple text in excel formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I am seeking some assistance in how to properly replace multiple criteria within a formula using VBA - Excel. I have a userform at the beginning of the macro where the user will select the month that they are wanting to run the report for. I am using the previous month's report as the template and need to update the formula to reflect the proper months accordingly. I am looking to have the formula be applied to an entire column of data. I am shifting each month in the formula forward one month to capture the previous four (4) months of data.

For example: I am running a report for AUG. I will be using the JUL report that was ran the previous month as the template.

The formula that is currently in the report:

```
  =sum('JUL18'!$E$19+'JUN18'!$E$19+'MAY18'!$E$19+'APR18'!$E$19)/B6
```

I would like the formula to update to:

```
  =sum('AUG18'!$E$19+'JUL18'!$E$19+'JUN18'!$E$19+'MAY18'!$E$19)/B6
```

The code I currently have is:

```
If FormMonth.Value = "AUG" Then
     Columns("D:D").Select
 Selection.Replace What:="JUL", Replacement:="AUG", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
 Selection.Replace What:="JUN", Replacement:="JUL", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
 Selection.Replace What:="MAY", Replacement:="JUN", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
 Selection.Replace What:="APR", Replacement:="MAY", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
 Selection.Replace What:="MAR", Replacement:="APR", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
 Selection.Replace What:="FEB", Replacement:="MAR", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End If
```

-The end result is as follows:

```
  =sum('AUG18'!$E$19+'AUG18'!$E$19+'JUN18'!$E$19+'MAY18'!$E$19)/B6
```

The first and last two months in the formula appear to update properly, however the JUN (supposed to update to JUL) jumps to AUG. It's as if it continues to loop through until it reaches the chosen form month.

Any ideas as to why this may be? Still becoming acclimated with VBA so the code may not be the prettiest.

Comment: Are you running this more than once?

Comment: @SJR - No, it is only running once. I have this same code repeated for each month. Each month is contained in an "if statement", as shown in the code above. It should be passing over all other months and only running the selected month "if statement" once. Well, at least that's what I'm shooting for!

Comment: I would check that as I can't see how that could happen otherwise. Try stepping through the code using F8 to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! I will step through it and see what I can find out.

Comment: Just a note: If any UDF's are involved, Excel will often run it twice for every once required. Excel "pre-runs" equations far enough to determine dependencies, then runs them again in the order of dependencies to get the final, correct answer.

Comment: I am finding that my columns("D:D").select may be a contributor! I attempt to run this code for columns("C:C"), however it changes data in columns("D:D"). This is changing data into columns("D:D") prior to this code being ran. Do I need to do a columns.range("D:D") instead?

Comment: Try replacing all of the `Selection` 's with `Columns("D:D")`; and remove the `Columns("D:D").Select` line. If you have any code triggered by worksheet calculations, you should also look into turning events off for the duration of your code, and on again once you've finished. Although you may also need to look into error handlers then, to make sure the events get turned back on even if there is an error....

Comment: Maybe you should post all your code.

Answer (score 1):

You really don’t need a macro, you can use indirect function.

formulas you will need:

'=TEXT(EOMONTH(B2,-1),"MMM")
'=SUM(INDIRECT(B5&"!A1"),INDIRECT(B6&"!A1"),INDIRECT(B7&"!A1"))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to reduce the amount of repetitive code. Also, removed instanced of `.Select`

```
Sub Test()

Dim Arr1: Arr1 = Array("JUL", "JUN", "MAY", "APR", "MAR", "FEB")
Dim Arr2: Arr2 = Array("AUG", "JUL", "JUN", "MAY", "APR", "MAR")

Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr2)
        .Replace What:=Arr1(i), Replacement:=Arr2(i), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```